# Traversal with .closest() fails

Tags: javascript, traversal

I'm puzzled why thew second traversal with .closest seems to fail in this simple example:

```js
 
        function testClosest(element) {
            let firstParentDiv = element.closest('div');
            console.log('First Parent Div ID:', firstParentDiv.id);

            let secondParentDiv = firstParentDiv.closest('div');
            console.log('Second Parent Div ID:', secondParentDiv ? secondParentDiv.id : 'None');
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test for .closest() Method</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="grandparent">
        Grandparent
        <div id="parent">
            Parent
            <div id="child">
                Child
                <button onclick="testClosest(this)">Test Closest</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

I'm expecting the second console log to say "parent" but instead it logs "child" again.
Why is the second traversal attempt not working?

Comment: What's closer to something than itself? From [MDN's documentation of `closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest): "The `closest()` method of the `Element` interface traverses the element and its parents (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the specified CSS selector."

Comment: You can try with `.parentElement.closest('div')`

Answer (score 0):

Return value

The closest ancestor Element or **itself**, which matches the selectors. If there are no such element, null.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

---

You may want the [.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) instead since it will begin with the parent element.

```js
let secondParentDiv = firstParentDiv.parentNode.closest("div");
```